# Starting new activity via using button

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have a problem about starting a new activity via using button.

I already checked the previous questions related to mine problem, one of them is almost same but solutions didn't work out for me. So here is my problem.

I have 2 activity, one called Acilis, second MainActivity,

So when app starts, Acilis.class starts and there are two buttons there, its suppose to start MainActivity.class after a button click. After I click application crashes. Here is my code

Manifest:

```
<activity
        android:name="com.example.workbench.Acilis"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>    
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.workbench.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.workbench.MAINACTIVITY" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Acilis.class

```
public class Acilis extends Activity{

Button erkek, kadin;
Intent intent = new Intent("com.example.workbench.MAINACTIVITY");

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.anasayfa);

    erkek = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_erkek);
    kadin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_kadin);

    erkek.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
            startActivity(intent);      
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);         
        }
    }); 
    kadin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            startActivity(intent);  
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        }
```

MainActivity.class

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    sayfa_no = 0;
    ileri = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button_ileri);
    geri = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button_geri);
    fav = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button_fav);

    ileri.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            sayfa_no++;
            sayfa.setText(sayfa_no + "/100");
        }
    }); 
    geri.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            sayfa_no--;
            sayfa.setText(sayfa_no + "/100");
        }
    });
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

I already take cover of my brackets don't worry, Eclipse doestn't give any error. I got semantic error I think.

LogCat:

```
06-17 10:59:41.369: E/AndroidRuntime(15450): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-17 10:59:41.369: E/AndroidRuntime(15450): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.workbench/com.example.workbench.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-17 10:59:41.369: E/AndroidRuntime(15450):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
06-17 10:59:41.369: E/AndroidRuntime(15450):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
06-17 10:59:41.369: E/AndroidRuntime(15450):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
06-17 10:59:41.369: E/AndroidRuntime(15450):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
06-17 10:59:41.369: E/AndroidRuntime(15450):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-17 10:59:41.369: E/AndroidRuntime(15450):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-17 10:59:41.369: E/AndroidRuntime(15450):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
06-17 10:59:41.369: E/AndroidRuntime(15450):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-17 10:59:41.369: E/AndroidRuntime(15450):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-17 10:59:41.369: E/AndroidRuntime(15450):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
```

Its too long error case, posted some part.

Thank you guys!

Comment: could be easily to underderstand what's happening if you post the whole stacktrace

Comment: @blackbelt this Intent intent = new Intent("com.example.workbench.MAINACTIVITY"); and in manifest android:name="com.example.workbench.MainActivity" does not match. Also he is calling setcontentView( layout)

Comment: please put logcat error message'

Comment: what is the meaning of `setContentView` after starting a different activity?!

Comment: @thepoosh it also starts a new layout.

Comment: Also post `MainActivity` code, I have doubt of `NPE` in it.

Comment: @The King. just mention this setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);   in the main activity as i mentioned below  http://stackoverflow.com/a/17145960/1835764.

Comment: I declared  new layout in MainActivity.class it now works thanks. I have a button problem now but anyway this one solved. Thank you guys.

Comment: @TheKing, post the entire logcat, don't worry about length, you are hiding all the important information about what happened instead of making it easier for us to help.

Comment: @thepoosh solved the problem now. Thank you for warning I will post the entire code next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ileri.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
```

This line cause `NullPointerException` in `MAinActivity` Class because you are accessing layout resource without calling `setContentView()` method in `onCreate()` of **MainActivity**.

Put  `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`

after `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);` in `onCreate()` of `MainActivity`.

Comment: Yes okay this one worked out thank you. Well now, ileri.button does give error, but MainActivity.class starts now thanks !

Comment: Sorry I am new to this site, here =)

Answer (score 0):

have you tried?

```
Intent intent;

intent = new Intent(Acilis.this, MainActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare your setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);  in MAINACTIVITY.class.

```
erkek.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub     
        intent  = new Intent(getapplicationcontext() , MAINACTIVITY.class); 
        startActivity(intent);      
       // setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);         
    }
});
```

Hope this will give you some solution.

Answer (score 0):

try by removing filters from Acilis activity:

```
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.workbench.Acilis"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

to

```
<activity android:name="com.example.workbench.Acilis" />
or
<activity android:name=".Acilis" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the intent filter for MainActivity in the manifest file

Answer (score -1):

just change it:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.example.workbench.MAINACTIVITY");
```

into:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Acilis.this, MainActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

and Remove intent filter from activity of MainActivity from manifest file.

Comment: Not Down Voter. But do you know the ways to start Activity using `Intent`?

Comment: Just for you. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html go through it.

Comment: @Segi check explicit and implicit intents in the android doc. i guess that's the reason your answer is downvoted

Comment: i know that. but my answer is not wrong. it is right in another way. you cant downvoted if answer is correct..you can only downvoted if it not works..

Comment: @Segi no your answer does not answer the op's question he has intent filter in manifest. so your answer does not hold good he to call the activity explicitly using fully qualified name

Answer (score -1):

Please remove on intent filter from the android manifeast

```
<intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.workbench.MAINACTIVITY" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
  </intent-filter>
```

resource alocation in on create method

please put this line and check it ,

```
intent  = new Intent(Acilis .this, MAINACTIVITY.class);
startActivity(intent)
```